# Monitoring CPU consumption during runtime of a python script on linux

Tags: linux, monitoring

I am running different python scripts for a same task and i would like to know how much CPU power is consumed by each of the script during runtime(average usage or highest usage percentage would suffice).
Usually, for time consumption monitoring, i use: `time python example.py`

But for CPU or memory consumption display at the end of execution, i could not find any command. Is there anything similar?
Thanks